# Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void isEmpty()

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, insert, method

I Get te following error on my testclass: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void isEmpty(). There are several answers to this but I still dont understand what is wrong with my testclass.

Class

```
public class CreateFactuurregel {
    public void CreateFactuurregel(){
        List<Account> acc= [SELECT Name,Debiteurenrnummer__c FROM Account WHERE Bestuurdersaansprakelijkheidsverzekering__c = true AND RecordTypeId ='0125800000010Rk'];
        for(integer x=0;x<acc.size();x++){
            Factuurregel__c fact =new Factuurregel__c(Organisatie__c=acc[x].Name, Debiteur__c = acc[x].Debiteurenrnummer__c ,
                                                      Aantal__c = 1, Product__c= 'Bestuurdersaansprakelijkheidsverzekering', Factuurdatum__c= date.today()
                                                     );
            insert fact;
        } 
    }
}
```

Test

```
@isTest
public class CreateFactuurregelTest {
    static testMethod void createFactuurregelstest() {
    Account acct = new Account(Name = 'testname', recordtypeId='0125800000010Rk',Bestuurdersaansprakelijkheidsverzekering__c=true);
    insert acct;

        CreateFactuurregel fr = new CreateFactuurregel();

        system.assert(!fr.isEmpty());
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, if you don't define that method on your class CreateFactuurregel, it will not exist.

Comment: Hi Thomas, welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to scroll through the [tour], read [ask], and visit the [help]. If you explain what you are trying to achieve, you are more likely to get a useful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll offer a couple notes here that you may find useful.

- [Never hard-code Ids](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices#Best_Practices_.2310:_Avoid_Hardcoding_IDs).

  Salesforce itself indicates it as a best practice to avoid such hard-coding, and it completely breaks your flexibility to migrate between orgs (except from full-copy sandbox environments to production).

  You can modify your query to filter on `RecordType.DeveloperName`:

  ```
  ... AND RecordType.DeveloperName = 'My_Record_Type'
  ```

  You can modify your test class to query for that `RecordType` and set its Id:

  ```
  RecordType myRecordType = [
      SELECT Id FROM RecordType
      WHERE SObjectType = 'Account'
      AND DeveloperName = 'My_Record_Type'
  ];
  insert new Account(/*other fields*/, RecordTypeId=myRecordType.Id);
  ```
- **Add informative assertion messages.** They make your tests way easier to maintain and understand.
- If you want to store some data outside the context of a method, you can do so by adding a property.

  For example, that might look like:

  ```
  public class MyClass
  {
      public List<Account> myAccounts;
      public MyClass()
      { // constructor block

          myAccounts = [/*some query*/]

      }
      public void myMethod()
      {
          // use myAccounts data here
      }
  }
  ```

  Now in your test, you can check if the proper records get queried:

  ```
  static testmethod void myTest()
  {
      // set up data

      Test.startTest();
          MyClass instance = new MyClass();
      Test.stopTest();

      system.assertNotEquals(null, instance.myAccounts, 'The collection should be initialized');
      system.assert(!instance.myAccounts.isEmpty(), 'The proper records should be queried');
  }
  ```